# How to add BackButton Facility MFSlidemenu?

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar, mfslidemenu

I have implemented MFSideMenu in my project .It works great, but now i want to implement back button facility to every view.

I try this but not working:

```
NSArray *array = [self.navigationController viewControllers];

[self.navigationController popToViewController:[array objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

Comment: i got solution to back bar button in mfslidemenu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Here is the Solution**

  ```
  HomeView *Home = [[HomeView alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomeView" bundle:nil];
  NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:Home];
  self.navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;
  ```