# how to go back in MFsidemenu?

Tags: ios, objective-c, popviewcontrolleranimated, mfslidemenu

i want to back on `MFSlidemenu` there is no functionality to go back in `MFSlidemenu`

i have tried this but result:

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:Viewcontroller animated:YES];
```

and this

```
 NSUInteger ownIndex = [self.navigationController.viewControllers indexOfObject:self];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:        
[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:ownIndex - 2] animated:YES];
```

Comment: it measns you need to show side menu on click back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[please check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39265673/how-to-add-backbutton-facility-mfslidemenu)

```
HomeView *Home = [[HomeView alloc]initWithNibName:@"HomeView" bundle:nil];
NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:Home];
self.navigationController.viewControllers = controllers;
```

Comment: Instead of reposting a previous answer, you should close the question as a duplicate of the other question.

Comment: @rmaddy i also want to close please tell me how?

Comment: You may not have enough rep. Normally you click on the Close link below the answer and choose Duplicate. Or click on the Flag link and choose Duplicate.

Comment: gerat bro @rmaddy

Comment: thank you @seggy and rmaddy